# Should I wrap every text-node with a <p> element?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I create a semantically and logically correct HTML5 document with a concious created document outline to satisfy search engines and other software which take advantage of element semantics.

The `<p>` element - 
I know I should not take its name, paragraph, too literally, but I am not sure If I **should** use it to wrap **every** text-node in the document?

Generally asked, **should** I wrap **every** text-node in the DOM with a `<p>` element, even the smallest text portions, or may I just write them *down* in the document?

Comment: <p> is for paragraphs, is each text node it's own paragraph?

Comment: I would like a general answer, if this makes sense, but to answer your comment: I use words which are stand-alone and they are technically there own "paragraph" but since they are actually only one word long they don't literally be one. And no, these single words don't really fit into the meaning of a heading element (<h1>, <h2>, etc.).

Comment: If the words are wrapped in a tag then they can be styled individually so I guess so. Maybe span would be useful? Although top & bottom margin / padding can't be added with a span.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I just want to know if I should markup any text with an element. (It's definetly not about styling!)

Comment: Oh lol, then nah who cares!

Comment: Search engines, disabled people and analytical software do care about semantics.

Comment: I really have no idea what you're asking for

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the definition of a [paragraph](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#paragraph) in the HTML5 spec, you'll see several examples of pieces of text not wrapped in `<p>` tags. So no, there is no requirement to wrap every scrap of text in `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently came across the same problem when I was working on making my own grid. Up until now I taught

tags were optional. And as far as I know they are. However I seem to be wrong about something. When I have:

```
<div>xyz</div>
```

I taught this was technically the same as:

```
<div><p>xyz</p></div>
```

But when I try to style it like

```
div > p {color: red}
```

The div with the p element works, but the one without doesn't. So it seems at least to me that they are not identical.

As a short answer to your question, I would recommend using P element around text when you are sure you will need to style it based on its parent. like in this case, the parent being a div. Otherwise for the most part you will get away with it. But its caveats like this that will come back to bite you later. I have an arguably "bad" habit of not using P tags unless I really need them because technically they are optional. But that's just me.

If this answer is not 100% correct, please let me know in comment instead of just voting down as I would like to learn the "correct" way as much as anyone else. So this is as much a question as it is an answer cause I am not 100% sure too. I'm left to thinking it is a matter of preference unless necessity dictates otherwise as in the case of styling above. But I would like to know what others think on this too.